# swift project scope, how to convert address to custom class?

Tags: swift, lldb

using `po` in swift project, how to convert address to custom class?

I know the default UIKit is using Objective-C

here is what I tried:

```
(lldb) po 0x7fe5d570f600
<ÊàëËØª‰Ω†Èªò.MineController: 0x7fe5d570f600>
```

I don't know what `ÊàëËØª‰Ω†Èªò` is

```
(lldb) po ((MineController *)0x7fe5d570f600)
error: <user expression 130>:1:3: use of undeclared identifier 'MineController'
((MineController *)0x7fe5d570f600)
  ^
error: <user expression 130>:1:19: expected expression
((MineController *)0x7fe5d570f600)
```

`SwiftSocket` is my project name

```
(lldb) po ((SwiftSocket.MineController *)0x7fe5d570f600)
error: <user expression 122>:1:3: use of undeclared identifier 'SwiftSocket'
((SwiftSocket.MineController *)0x7fe5d570f600)
  ^
error: <user expression 122>:1:31: expected expression
((SwiftSocket.MineController *)0x7fe5d570f600)
```

I also tried

```
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- unsafeBitCast(0x7fe5d570f600, to: MineController.self)
error: <EXPR>:3:35: error: cannot find 'MineController' in scope
unsafeBitCast(0x7fe5d570f600, to: MineController.self)
```

Comment: The first "po" is the ObjC runtime's generic NSObject printing.  Swift classes that derive from NSObject or use @objc are made to look like ObjC classes as well as Swift ones.  The first bit should be the module name, but it looks like the ObjC runtime didn't get that part right.  You're never going to convince the C expression parser to cast something as a pointer to ObjC types, so the middle ones are not likely to work.  The last one seems more likely to work, but lldb can't find the type for MineController.  Without more knowledge of your project it's hard to guess why that might be.

Comment: I guess any iOS project will do. Any similar example is welcomed

Comment: Just an easy  iOS project , there is an custom class UIViewController `MineController ` in it

Comment: If you have a simple project that you can share that shows this, please file a bug with bugs.swift.org or the Apple bug reporter, with instructions for how you got to the point where you tried the expressions.  It's odd that the ObjC printer is getting the module name wrong, and that the swift expression can't find that class type.

Comment: Thx, now people use Apple's Radar system to report bugs. I will do later